# $(document).on('click') event fires without clicking. using e.stopPropagation() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am using jQuery to set and receive a cookie. If the cookie is set, show some HTML code to the user specific to the cookie set next time the page is loaded. If you click a vertical nav on the page, this will set the cookie to a new value to pull up different HTML next time the page is loaded.

**The problem:**
The click handler is executing the code inside of it when the page is loaded, which sets the cookie to an incorrect value. I looked into bubbling and preventing it, and using the stopPropagation() method is not working. All of the js is contained within $(document).ready()

**The javascript:**

```
     if ( $('#courseTab').length ) {
          $('#courseTab li').on('click', function(event) {
            var cookieValue =  $(this).find('a').attr('id');
            setCookie("current_flex_tab", cookieValue, 30);
            console.log("INSIDE CLICK EVENT " + getCookie("current_flex_tab"));
            event.stopPropagation();
          });

          if ( getCookie("current_flex_tab") ) {
            console.log( "OUTSIDE OF CLICK EVENT " + getCookie("current_flex_tab") );
            var currentFlexTab = getCookie("current_flex_tab");
            var currentFlexTabId = "#" + currentFlexTab;

            // Prepares and sends ajax request for current flex study tab
            var params = {"view" : $(currentFlexTabId).attr('href').substring(1)}
            ajaxHandler.requestData( $(currentFlexTabId).attr('value') , params, "POST", currentFlexTab);

          }
      }
```

**Screenshot of Console Output:**
![image of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OMx3.png)

**The HTML:**

```
 <div class="col-xs-2 visible-md visible-lg" id="courseTab">
      <h6 class="text-muted">FLEX STUDY</h6>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>
          <a class="data" id="subject_outline_tasks" data-toggle="tab" href="#subject_outline" value="course.getTaskData">Outlines
                        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="subject_outline">
                      </a>
        </li>
                <li>
          <a class="data" id="video_tasks" data-toggle="tab" href="#video" value="course.getTaskData">Lectures
                        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="video">
                      </a>
        </li>
                <li>
          <a class="data" id="essay_tasks" data-toggle="tab" href="#essay" value="course.getTaskData">Essay PQ
                        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="essay">
                      </a>
        </li>
              </ul>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me figure out why the click event is firing when the page is loaded? I have also opted not to include the setCookie plugin as it has been working 100% ok throughout the rest of the site. If there is a need, I can definitely add it to the post. Thank you

Comment: There is no `$(document).on('click')` in your quoted code.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because the quoted code definitely will not log the `"INSIDE"` line unless you click an `li` inside the `#courseTab` element. [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... or unless something triggers the click programmatically. Which might possibly be what's happening elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I have created an MCVE (http://jsfiddle.net/h4evapt4/) and was not able to replicate the issue using that, so T.J's inclination that "select isn't broken," in this case, is probably correct. I will look elsewhere in the application to see if I can determine the root problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Patrick: Probably best to delete this question and post a new one when/if you need to. Good luck with it,

Answer (score -1):

When I've run into issue with attaching event handlers, I've resolved the issue by using the on() method to attach click handlers instead of jQuery's "shortcut" methods.

Try using this syntax.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mySelector', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The way the OP did theirs is functionally identical to your second example. See the docs for `on`.

Comment: Uhm, no they didn't.  The second is a shortcut for the trigger function and it's clear as day they used the .on function to attach the event listener, and they are two different means of attaching event listeners which will achieve different results based on how and where they are used... That summation is indeed from the jQuery docs.

Comment: @ Brian: Perhaps there's a misunderstanding. The OP has `$('#courseTab li').on('click', function(event) {/*...*/});` and you've said you're not sure that's correct and suggested `$('#courseTab li').click(function(event) {/*...*/});` That is functionally identical to what the OP did. `.on("click", function...)` and `.click(function...)` are two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: @TJ, these things are always good for us to brush up on the fine details of syntax and purpose, and my suggestion was indeed functionality the same. Had sugestion right in my brain but reversed when i typed.  Will edit post when i get to work, good catch.